# Same SQL stall on server but work on local ( on slower machine )

Tags: mysql, join, php

I have this strange issue that because of my limited knowledge about Mysql I cannot understand, I will really appreciate if somebody can enlighten me and point me to how to debug the issue.

> **Scenario:**
>   I have a Live Magento store and a local replication of it (same code/DB)

On both enviroments `Apache` service and `MySql` service are on same machine (the main difference is than on the live server the site is inside a chroot).

I have replicated the `MySql` live configuration on my local environment but there are still 2 main diff:

- `MySql` version
- this option `table_cache = 2048` is not working on my local

**Live `MySql`:**
`mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.40, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2`
**Local `MySql`:**
`mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.25, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper`

**The issue**

I have this query that retrieve products and do some joins (see below).

My local machine is much slower than live server anyway the same SQL on my local takes about 4 seconds on live server it basically nerver ends:

- `SHOW PROCESSLIST`say the query is in `state` `sending data`

I have found out that the main bottleneck is the join between `catalog_product_entity` (rows 21,113) on the `core_url_rewrite` table (rows 892,997).

```
SELECT
  `main_table`.`entity_id`,
  `ur`.`request_path` AS `url`
FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `main_table`
  INNER JOIN `catalog_product_website` AS `w`
    ON main_table.entity_id = w.product_id
  LEFT JOIN `core_url_rewrite` AS `ur`
    ON main_table.entity_id = ur.product_id AND ur.category_id IS NULL AND ur.store_id = 2 AND ur.is_system = 1
WHERE (w.website_id = '1')
```

I have tried to `limit` the query, the result is that if I `limit` it to 10 items the first 3/4 pages can be retrieved while after that it start to hang. ( every time I increment the `limit` by 10, or the number of pages retrieved, the query take 10/20 sec. more on the live server)

**MORE INFOS**

**Runnig the SQL with `EXPLAIN` command**:

Even if the table structure is the same, I can see some difference here but I'm not sure if they are meaningful info:

- `ref` and `extra` value are not the same on live/local for table `core_url_rewrite`

**LIVE SERVER**

```
[id] => 1
[select_type] => SIMPLE
[table] => w
[type] => ref
[possible_keys] => PRIMARY,IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_WEBSITE_WEBSITE_ID
[key] => IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_WEBSITE_WEBSITE_ID
[key_len] => 2
[ref] => const
[rows] => 10868
[Extra] => Using index

[id] => 1
[select_type] => SIMPLE
[table] => main_table
[type] => eq_ref
[possible_keys] => PRIMARY
[key] => PRIMARY
[key_len] => 4
[ref] => LIVE.w.product_id
[rows] => 1
[Extra] => 

[id] => 1
[select_type] => SIMPLE
[table] => ur
[type] => ref
[possible_keys] => IDX_CORE_URL_REWRITE_STORE_ID,FK_CORE_URL_REWRITE_CTGR_ID_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_ENTT_ID,FK_CORE_URL_REWRITE_PRODUCT_ID_CATALOG_CATEGORY_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID
[key] => FK_CORE_URL_REWRITE_CTGR_ID_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_ENTT_ID
[key_len] => 5
[ref] => const
[rows] => 10
[Extra] =>
```

**LOCAL**

```
[id] => 1
[select_type] => SIMPLE
[table] => w
[type] => ref
[possible_keys] => PRIMARY,IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_WEBSITE_WEBSITE_ID
[key] => IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_WEBSITE_WEBSITE_ID
[key_len] => 2
[ref] => const
[rows] => 10622
[Extra] => Using index

[id] => 1
[select_type] => SIMPLE
[table] => main_table
[type] => eq_ref
[possible_keys] => PRIMARY
[key] => PRIMARY
[key_len] => 4
[ref] => PJ_LOCAL.w.product_id
[rows] => 1
[Extra] => 

[id] => 1
[select_type] => SIMPLE
[table] => ur
[type] => ref
[possible_keys] => IDX_CORE_URL_REWRITE_STORE_ID,FK_CORE_URL_REWRITE_CTGR_ID_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_ENTT_ID,FK_CORE_URL_REWRITE_PRODUCT_ID_CATALOG_CATEGORY_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID
[key] => FK_CORE_URL_REWRITE_PRODUCT_ID_CATALOG_CATEGORY_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID
[key_len] => 5
[ref] => PJ_LOCAL.w.product_id
[rows] => 22
[Extra] => Using where
```

**INDEX INFO**

**TABLE `catalog_product_entity`**

```
[Table] => catalog_product_entity
[Non_unique] => 0
[Key_name] => PRIMARY
[Seq_in_index] => 1
[Column_name] => entity_id
[Collation] => A
[Cardinality] => 21455
[Sub_part] => 
[Packed] => 
[Null] => 
[Index_type] => BTREE
[Comment] => 
[Index_comment] => 

[Table] => catalog_product_entity
[Non_unique] => 1
[Key_name] => IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_ENTITY_TYPE_ID
[Seq_in_index] => 1
[Column_name] => entity_type_id
[Collation] => A
[Cardinality] => 2
[Sub_part] => 
[Packed] => 
[Null] => 
[Index_type] => BTREE
[Comment] => 
[Index_comment] => 

[Table] => catalog_product_entity
[Non_unique] => 1
[Key_name] => IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID
[Seq_in_index] => 1
[Column_name] => attribute_set_id
[Collation] => A
[Cardinality] => 16
[Sub_part] => 
[Packed] => 
[Null] => 
[Index_type] => BTREE
[Comment] => 
[Index_comment] => 

[Table] => catalog_product_entity
[Non_unique] => 1
[Key_name] => IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_SKU
[Seq_in_index] => 1
[Column_name] => sku
[Collation] => A
[Cardinality] => 21455
[Sub_part] => 
[Packed] => 
[Null] => YES
[Index_type] => BTREE
[Comment] => 
[Index_comment] =>
```

**TABLE `core_url_rewrite`**

```
[Table] => core_url_rewrite
[Non_unique] => 0
[Key_name] => PRIMARY
[Seq_in_index] => 1
[Column_name] => url_rewrite_id
[Collation] => A
[Cardinality] => 851468
[Sub_part] => 
[Packed] => 
[Null] => 
[Index_type] => BTREE
[Comment] => 
[Index_comment] => 

[Table] => core_url_rewrite
[Non_unique] => 0
[Key_name] => UNQ_CORE_URL_REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_STORE_ID
[Seq_in_index] => 1
[Column_name] => request_path
[Collation] => A
[Cardinality] => 851468
[Sub_part] => 
[Packed] => 
[Null] => YES
[Index_type] => BTREE
[Comment] => 
[Index_comment] => 

[Table] => core_url_rewrite
[Non_unique] => 0
[Key_name] => UNQ_CORE_URL_REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_STORE_ID
[Seq_in_index] => 2
[Column_name] => store_id
[Collation] => A
[Cardinality] => 851468
[Sub_part] => 
[Packed] => 
[Null] => 
[Index_type] => BTREE
[Comment] => 
[Index_comment] => 

[Table] => core_url_rewrite
[Non_unique] => 0
[Key_name] => UNQ_CORE_URL_REWRITE_ID_PATH_IS_SYSTEM_STORE_ID
[Seq_in_index] => 1
[Column_name] => id_path
[Collation] => A
[Cardinality] => 851468
[Sub_part] => 
[Packed] => 
[Null] => YES
[Index_type] => BTREE
[Comment] => 
[Index_comment] => 

[Table] => core_url_rewrite
[Non_unique] => 0
[Key_name] => UNQ_CORE_URL_REWRITE_ID_PATH_IS_SYSTEM_STORE_ID
[Seq_in_index] => 2
[Column_name] => is_system
[Collation] => A
[Cardinality] => 851468
[Sub_part] => 
[Packed] => 
[Null] => YES
[Index_type] => BTREE
[Comment] => 
[Index_comment] => 

[Table] => core_url_rewrite
[Non_unique] => 0
[Key_name] => UNQ_CORE_URL_REWRITE_ID_PATH_IS_SYSTEM_STORE_ID
[Seq_in_index] => 3
[Column_name] => store_id
[Collation] => A
[Cardinality] => 851468
[Sub_part] => 
[Packed] => 
[Null] => 
[Index_type] => BTREE
[Comment] => 
[Index_comment] => 

[Table] => core_url_rewrite
[Non_unique] => 1
[Key_name] => IDX_CORE_URL_REWRITE_TARGET_PATH_STORE_ID
[Seq_in_index] => 1
[Column_name] => target_path
[Collation] => A
[Cardinality] => 85146
[Sub_part] => 
[Packed] => 
[Null] => YES
[Index_type] => BTREE
[Comment] => 
[Index_comment] => 

[Table] => core_url_rewrite
[Non_unique] => 1
[Key_name] => IDX_CORE_URL_REWRITE_TARGET_PATH_STORE_ID
[Seq_in_index] => 2
[Column_name] => store_id
[Collation] => A
[Cardinality] => 85146
[Sub_part] => 
[Packed] => 
[Null] => 
[Index_type] => BTREE
[Comment] => 
[Index_comment] => 

[Table] => core_url_rewrite
[Non_unique] => 1
[Key_name] => IDX_CORE_URL_REWRITE_ID_PATH
[Seq_in_index] => 1
[Column_name] => id_path
[Collation] => A
[Cardinality] => 851468
[Sub_part] => 
[Packed] => 
[Null] => YES
[Index_type] => BTREE
[Comment] => 
[Index_comment] => 

[Table] => core_url_rewrite
[Non_unique] => 1
[Key_name] => IDX_CORE_URL_REWRITE_STORE_ID
[Seq_in_index] => 1
[Column_name] => store_id
[Collation] => A
[Cardinality] => 2
[Sub_part] => 
[Packed] => 
[Null] => 
[Index_type] => BTREE
[Comment] => 
[Index_comment] => 

[Table] => core_url_rewrite
[Non_unique] => 1
[Key_name] => FK_CORE_URL_REWRITE_CTGR_ID_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_ENTT_ID
[Seq_in_index] => 1
[Column_name] => category_id
[Collation] => A
[Cardinality] => 104
[Sub_part] => 
[Packed] => 
[Null] => YES
[Index_type] => BTREE
[Comment] => 
[Index_comment] => 

[Table] => core_url_rewrite
[Non_unique] => 1
[Key_name] => FK_CORE_URL_REWRITE_PRODUCT_ID_CATALOG_CATEGORY_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID
[Seq_in_index] => 1
[Column_name] => product_id
[Collation] => A
[Cardinality] => 38703
[Sub_part] => 
[Packed] => 
[Null] => YES
[Index_type] => BTREE
[Comment] => 
[Index_comment] =>
```

**CREATE TABLE INFOS**

**[Table] => catalog_product_entity**

```
[Create Table] => CREATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity` (
`entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Entity ID',
`entity_type_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Entity Type ID',
`attribute_set_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Attribute Set ID',
`type_id` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'simple' COMMENT 'Type ID',
`sku` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'SKU',
`has_options` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Has Options',
`required_options` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Required Options',
`created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Creation Time',
`updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Update Time',
`absolute_price` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`absolute_weight` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`sku_policy` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`),
KEY `IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_ENTITY_TYPE_ID` (`entity_type_id`),
KEY `IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID` (`attribute_set_id`),
KEY `IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_SKU` (`sku`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ATTR_SET_ID_EAV_ATTR_SET_ATTR_SET_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_set_id`) REFERENCES `eav_attribute_set` (`attribute_set_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_TYPE_ID_EAV_ENTT_TYPE_ENTT_TYPE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_type_id`) REFERENCES `eav_entity_type` (`entity_type_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=34952 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Catalog Product Table'
```

**[Table] => core_url_rewrite**

```
[Create Table] => CREATE TABLE `core_url_rewrite` (
`url_rewrite_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Rewrite Id',
`store_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Store Id',
`id_path` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Id Path',
`request_path` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Request Path',
`target_path` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Target Path',
`is_system` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT '1' COMMENT 'Defines is Rewrite System',
`options` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Options',
`description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Deascription',
`category_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Category Id',
`product_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Product Id',
PRIMARY KEY (`url_rewrite_id`),
UNIQUE KEY `UNQ_CORE_URL_REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_STORE_ID` (`request_path`,`store_id`),
UNIQUE KEY `UNQ_CORE_URL_REWRITE_ID_PATH_IS_SYSTEM_STORE_ID` (`id_path`,`is_system`,`store_id`),
KEY `IDX_CORE_URL_REWRITE_TARGET_PATH_STORE_ID` (`target_path`,`store_id`),
KEY `IDX_CORE_URL_REWRITE_ID_PATH` (`id_path`),
KEY `IDX_CORE_URL_REWRITE_STORE_ID` (`store_id`),
KEY `FK_CORE_URL_REWRITE_CTGR_ID_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_ENTT_ID` (`category_id`),
KEY `FK_CORE_URL_REWRITE_PRODUCT_ID_CATALOG_CATEGORY_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID` (`product_id`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_CORE_URL_REWRITE_CTGR_ID_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_category_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT `FK_CORE_URL_REWRITE_PRODUCT_ID_CATALOG_CATEGORY_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT `FK_CORE_URL_REWRITE_STORE_ID_CORE_STORE_STORE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`store_id`) REFERENCES `core_store` (`store_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3143682 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Url Rewrites'
```

Comment: Did you try the `explain` command to see how the SQL is behaving? Do both the live server and your local machine have the same memory used by the database? Databases benefit more from memory than CPU.

Comment: local ha 8gb ram,  live 32 gb... I'm trying the explain command

Comment: The EXPLAIN will show, but if table structure is the same, my guess is 5.6 has just better plan (and maybe some optimization).

Comment: but the query is not so heavy and the difference in time is huge, I doubt the optimization on mysql 5.6 are so big ...

Comment: I found out some difference in the explain ... I'm not sure if they are relevant

Comment: They probably are (at least partially). Can you add table/index information too, so we can see what each index contains?

Comment: I have added the index info for the two main tables

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each of the three tables.

Comment: Done.
I'm running the `SQL` using `php` that also for sure make a difference ... how can I test it without php ?

Comment: @WonderLand You can use [commandline mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql.html).

Comment: thx, I did and the problem is the same, I'm trying to downgrade my local mysql to to same live version ...

Comment: @WonderLand which client sent the query has no effect in deciding what plan to use for its execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably related to indexes and Mysql 5.6 handles certain query differently:
as you can see your local version for table `core_url_rewrite` Explain shows [Extra] => Using where (your live does not).
Your left join is probably causing the issue.

Try to run the query without the left join on both server and see if you get the same performance.
If you do, you know the left JOIN is cause Mysql to run the query differently on both server. (i'm assuming you have the same amount of data on both).
I don't see catalog_product_website table definition listed. Apparently it is using IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_WEBSITE_WEBSITE_ID (which includes the website_id).

Your left join

```
 LEFT JOIN `core_url_rewrite` AS `ur`
    ON main_table.entity_id = ur.product_id AND ur.category_id IS NULL AND ur.store_id = 2 AND ur.is_system = 1
WHERE ...
```

IS same as:

```
 LEFT JOIN `core_url_rewrite` AS `ur`
    ON main_table.entity_id = ur.product_id 
WHERE ...
AND ur.category_id IS NULL AND ur.store_id = 2 AND ur.is_system = 1
```

On live server,  I would add 2 index on table :

```
ALTER TABLE `core_url_rewrite` ADD INDEX `idx_storeid_is_system_cat_id` (`store_id`,`is_system`,`category_id`);
ALTER TABLE `core_url_rewrite` ADD INDEX `idx_storeid_is_system_prod_id` (`store_id`,`is_system`,`product_id`);
```

and see which one gets picked up. (Mysql indexes can be tricky)

Optimizing the table could also fix the issue. Sometimes indexes are thrown out of place or get fragmented (if data is often updated / deleted).

Comment: how can I understand which index is used ?

Comment: Use explain, it will show what index (key) is used. (Possible keys are potential key Mysql could use for query, key is the index used). Len is the length of the index used.

Comment: 2 things, adding the index fix the issue !!!! anyway I cannot find out which one is used key shows this index is now used ... `FK_CORE_URL_REWRITE_CTGR_ID_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_ENTT_ID`